# is there a more efficient way to split a column based on characters?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis, data-wrangling

I have a column named 'email' and I want to create a new column named 'company' that will take strings after the '@' up until the first '.' .

```
finaldf['email'].head(3)

0     person@company.com.br
1    woman@company.com.br
2    people@company.fr
```

I was able  to figure out a way of doing it but it would take a couple of steps (lines of code)

Comment: Can you share the code you are working with?

Answer (score 0):

use extract to capture the string b/w @ and period.

```
df['email'].str.extract(r'@(.*?)\.' )
```

```
          0
0   company
1   company
2   company
```

Comment: thank you. It is giving me the string including the dot (.) anyway to not include it?

Comment: did you copy/paste the code or typed it? sounds like **\.** are within the parenthesis. It should be outside of the parenthesis after ?. the inner parenthesis are the capture group